# SailsJs ajax-form validation

Tags: sails.js, ajax-forms

Is there a way I can run a function on the built-in vue component "ajax-form" in SailsJs? I want it to run when the form is submitted and do some validation, but take place before the data is sent to the back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax-form is super handy. And it's well supported by Sails.js

Here is an example of how you can set up your form:

```
<ajax-form action="createOneThing" :syncing.sync="syncing" :cloud-error.sync="cloudError" 
:form-errors.sync="createThingFormErrors" :form-data="createThingFormData"
:form-rules="createThingFormRules" @submitted="submittedCreateThingForm($event)">

   <label for="thing-name">Thing Name:</label>
   <input class="form-control" :class="[createThingFormErrors.thingName ? 'is-invalid' : '']" 
   type="text" id="thing-name" v-model="createThingFormData.thingName">
   <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="createThingFormErrors.thingName">Make up a name for your thing.</div>


   <ajax-button type="submit" :syncing="syncing">Delete</ajax-button>

</ajax-form>
```

Now you have to make sure you set your objects in your page script under `data`:

```
    createThingFormData: {},
    createThingFormErrors: {},
    createThingFormRules: {
     thingName: { required: true },
    }
```

You can also check out this post for more usage info about Ajax 
https://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-ajax/

Comment: will is action createOneThing processed or what does it trigger, a http request?

Comment: @windchime the ajax form will call the action: createOneThing. If your using Sails you can use `sails generate action createOneMoreThing` and it will make your post route for you!

Comment: Oh I also wanted to add that you'll need to run `sails run scripts/rebuild-cloud-sdk` after you create a new action.